# Logging in Databricks Python Notebooks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

Coming from a Java background, I'm missing a global logging framework/configuration for Python Notebooks, like log4j.

In log4j I would configure a log4j configuration file, that sends
logs directy to Azure Log Analytics.

How do I do this in Databricks for Python Notebooks?
I would like to call something like: `log.warn("please take care...")` 
and it should be sent to Azure Log Analytics, with some meta data (e.g. notebook name, start time of job, etc.)

Comment: Can you provide some more information so that community will help you to solve the issue.

Comment: I would like to call `log.warn("...")` and the logs need to be sent to Azure Log Analytics. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Configure Databricks to send logs to Azure Log Analytics

I configure spark cluster to send logs to the Azure log analytics workspace

### Steps to set up the library:

**Step 1:** Clone the repository

[image]

**Step 2:** Set Azure  Databricks workspace

**Step 3:** Install Azure Databricks CLI and set up authentication.

Run  following command

```
pip install databricks-cli
```

configure the CLI to use a personal access token, run the following command:

```
databricks configure --token
```

The command begins by issuing the prompt:

```
Databricks Host (should begin with https://):
```

Enter per-workspace URL, with the format  `https://adb-<workspace-id>.<random-number>.azuredatabricks.net`.

The command continues by issuing the prompt to enter personal access token:

```
Token:
```

To generate token Open menu by clicking on email id in the top right corner of menu bar -> Open User Settings -> Click on the Generate new token button -> click on generate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 4:** Install

- **Java Development Kit (JDK) version 1.8**
- **Scala language SDK 2.12**
- **Apache Maven 3.6.3**
- Now open the terminal where extracted the files are present and type these commands.

```
    M2_HOME='apache-maven-3.8.6'
    
    PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
    
    export PATH
    
    mvn -version
```

**Step5:** Build the Azure Databricks monitoring library**

**Using docker**

- Open terminal and type the following command [first change directory to /spark-monitoring]

```
docker run -it --rm -v %cd%:/spark-monitoring -v "%USERPROFILE%/.m2":/root/.m2 mcr.microsoft.com/java/maven:8-zulu-debian10 /spark-monitoring/build.sh
```

[image]

**Step 6:** Configure the Databricks workspace

- **Create directory**

```
dbfs mkdirs dbfs:/databricks/spark-monitoring
```

- Open /src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh file and add log analytics workspace key and id.

[image]

[image]

Azure key vault is also used here for security reasons

- Now Enter your AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, AZ_RSRC_GRP_NAME, AZ_RSRC_PROV_NAMESPACE, AZ_RSRC_TYPE, AZ_RSRC_NAME

```
LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_ID=$LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_ID

LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_KEY=$LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_KEY

export AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=d2738032-56cs-45cc-sdfs-2a906b237yhsg #your azure databricks subscription id

export AZ_RSRC_GRP_NAME=PipelineML #your resource group name

export AZ_RSRC_PROV_NAMESPACE=Microsoft.Databricks

export AZ_RSRC_TYPE=workspaces

export AZ_RSRC_NAME=pipelinemachinelearning #your databricks workspace name
```

### **Set up log analytics workspace**

- Open Log Analytics workspace

[image]

- Click on create

[image]

- Write name of instance and resource group and click on review and create

[image]

- define log analytics workspace secrets in the vault.

[image]

- create scope in databricks notebook
- Append secrets/createScope at the end of databricks url

[image]

- Enter the scope name and get the azure key vault DNS name and key resource ID from the azure key vault

Open log analytics workspace secrets, copy the vault URI and paste it in the DNS name and resource ID to resource ID.

[image]

- Click on Create

[image]

**Step 7:**
copy src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh to the directory created in Step 6 and also copy all jars files to src/target

```
dbfs cp src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh dbfs:/databricks/spark-monitoring/spark-monitoring.sh

dbfs cp --overwrite --recursive src/target/ dbfs:/databricks/spark-monitoring/
```

**Step 8:** create cluster in databricks workspace and open advance options

- First select your preferred cluster

[image]

- open advance options and add two more env variables like this

Format: {{secrets/{your scope name}/{your secret name in key vault}}}

[image]

- add this script to Init scripts

[image]

click on create cluster

**Testing by sending logs to azure logs analytics**

- Create a new notebook in azure databricks

[image]

Run both cells

- Visit Azure Log Analytics workspaces now visit to logs section

[image]

- open Custom Logs if don’t see customs logs restart cluster
- Write a query and click on run, now logs are visible

```
SparkLoggingEvent_CL

| where Message contains "Testing for log"
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I'm gonna test this soon and give you feedback.

Comment: Could you add on how to change the log level for notebooks of even certain notebooks if this is possible.